# Gatsby 4 dynamic routes with Directus data seems imposible

Tags: graphql, gatsby, directus

I'm trying to create dynamic routing. Lets say we are building a blog.

The graphql data i get from Directus looks like this:

```
{
  Directus {
    Posts {
      id
      slug
      Title
      Body
    }
  }
}
```

and this seems to be a problem. No matter how i try to create the routes, Gatsby insists that the data structure should be with nodes instead of just an array. I have tried with the  "File System Route API" which throws an error because of the missing nodes, the same thing happens if i try to define with "createPages" in gatsby-node.js.

Any help or suggestion is much appreciated...

Comment: If you can share the code of the "impossible" workaround you've tried would definitely help. The trials on the `createPages` or the File system route API when the error rises, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working... The solution is more simple then any guides i found on google, so here it comes, if anyone else ends up in the same situation.

Use the old cratePage method in a gatsby-node.js file, in root of project. I used this very simple code:

```
const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { data } = await graphql(`
    query Projects {
      Directus {
        Posts {
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  data.Directus.Posts.forEach(post => {
    actions.createPage({
      path: "/blog/" + post.slug,
      component: path.resolve("./src/components/blog.js"),
      context: { slug: post.slug },
    })
  })
}
```

And here's a link to useful information: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L32Vx_bEZhA